# Is there any way to import a .json model into Blender?

Tags: import, file-format

I need to find a way to import some .json models into Blender, and it seems I can't just import them the same way I can import a .obj model. So is there some way to convert a .json model to a .obj model, or another file type Blender can import? I've tried using Blockbench for this, but I think it only works with Minecraft recourse pack .json models, as those are the only models that will ever actually load in it. Thank you to anyone who can help me figure this out.

Comment: Have you found this addon here? https://github.com/warmwaffles/io_mesh_json and here with https://www.barneyparker.com/blender-json-import-export-plugin/ comments

Answer (score 2):

Have you found this addon here? https://github.com/warmwaffles/io_mesh_json and here with https://www.barneyparker.com/blender-json-import-export-plugin/ comments

Comment: @ZDUDE9 Please accept this answer with the green checkmark if it helped you.

Comment: the first link is only for exporting, and the second is a 404.