# import Mocap Json into Blender

Tags: animation, import, motion-capture

I have a Json file that has, for each frame, a cam coordinate and the poistion of each bone from a skeleton (see screenshot). I was wondering what was the quickest way to import it into blender ( like applying it to a skeleton for instance).

[image: json screenshot]

Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118822/is-there-any-way-to-import-a-json-model-into-blender

Comment: hmm it's not quite the same at this user wanted to import model stored in json meanwhile I want to import mocap stored in json.

Comment: What does the "positioning" of a bone look like, is it a quaternion with four values (`(0.707, 0, 0.707, 0)`)?

Comment: yes, 4 position times 2 for each bone, it is the data format coming out of openpose. I'm currently perusing how to export in bhv from openpose at it seems a easier but under developed at the moment.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution.  I would also like to use openpose data in blender or iclone

Comment: Just found this it converts openpose data to bvh. MocapNET https://github.com/FORTH-ModelBasedTracker/MocapNET